# How to synchronize build variants among apps

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, build-variant

I am working on a project that contains multiple applications. Several of them contain the same flavors. The same values on a flavor dimension, precisely.

I would like to have their value synchronized, if possible automatically. Otherwise, I would like it to show there is a conflict.

To summarize the situation, I would like the build variant selection pane to behave for unrelated applications of the same project the same as it works for module being a dependency of an app.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio only changes things based on the "leaf nodes" related to what you are changing, and thus won't ever link up the Apps. I had this same problem and solved it by writing my own [Android Studio Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14450-build-variant-quick-selector)